# how to implement a catalog with pagination

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working on a catalog with pagination, I'm redirecting all my requests to an index file and making friendly urls from there,

my catalog has some filters to search products, when you apply some filters and then get into a product and click the back button in the browser, it goes to the catalog page and loses all the previously applied filters.

I get the filter parameters through javascript and I send them through ajax via POST to my php controller.

How should I correctly implement this??

Comment: simple way to use GET variables in uri ?page=1&product=goods

Comment: but I'm doing friendly urls and that will make them kind of messy

Comment: is it similar to .htaccess url rewrite??

Comment: thats it, i redirect every request to my index and from there I create a custom url and depending on the request i redirect it to the attached controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save the filters in the cookies for a little period of time.

Comment: There is a better way, you can use LocalStorage, to stock the filters in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You need to grab the amount of data to filter, and in ajax you ll provide the boundaries on this pool.

lets say an example : with a pool of 75 data rows, 30 results per page.
first you have to calculate your amount of pages, here ceil(75/30), so here you got 3 pages.

if you are on page 1 and you display the results 1 to 30.
You have to calculate the begining of your dataset, here 1 : ( (current_page-1)x number of result +1) so 0 x 30 +1

on click on next page, you have to provide content for the second page, it means starting from (2-1)x30 + 1 : 31

Last page, you start from (3-1)x30 + 1 : 61

each time you have to clear your data displayed on the js callback and display the new array you just got.

Hope it is clear.

Comment: hehe I already have that , my question was about preserving the filtered data after changing current url and going backwards then. Thank  you anyway